# How to calculate determinant of $tI+\mathbf {1}\mathbf {1}^{\top}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, positive-definite

How to calculate determinant of $tI+\mathbf {1}\mathbf {1}^{\top}$ where $I$ is the identity matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbf {1}=[1,\dots,1]^{\top}$.

Can we make it positive or negative matrix by changing $t$?

Comment: ignore the $tI$ for now, the eigenvalues of the fixed part are well known.......then $tI$  adds $t$ to each eigenvalue, and the determinant is that product

Comment: @Will Jagy: thank you! so the determinant is $t^{n-1}(n+t)?$

Comment: Maybe first describe the matrix $\mathbf {1}^{\top}\mathbf {1}$.  What are its entries?  What is its rank?

Comment: Use the Weinstein-Aronszajn identity $\det (I_n + AB) = \det(I_m + BA)$ where $A$ is $n\times m$, and $B$ is $m\times n$, respectively. So, $\det(tI + 11^\mathsf{T}) = t^n\det (I + t^{-1}11^\mathsf{T}) = t^n(1 + t^{-1}1^\mathsf{T} 1 ) = t^n(1 + t^{-1}n)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably mean $t  + ^$ instead of $t  + ^$, since otherwise you'd be adding a scalar to a matrix. In this case it is a direct mechanical computation via the

[Matrix Determinant Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma)

$$
\det \left(\mathbf {A} +\mathbf {uv} ^{\textsf {T}}\right)
=\det \left(\mathbf {A} \right)+\mathbf {v} ^{\textsf {T}}\mathrm {adj} \left(\mathbf {A} \right)\mathbf {u}
\underset{\text{if $\exists A^{-1}$}}{=}\left(1+\mathbf {v} ^{\textsf {T}}\mathbf {A} ^{-1}\mathbf {u} \right)\,\det \left(\mathbf {A} \right)
$$

Thus

$$
\det(t_n + ^)= \det(t_n) \cdot(1+\tfrac{1}{t}^) = t^n(1+\tfrac{n}{t}) = (n+t)t^{n-1}
$$